# Count by group as part of a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the following SQL server query:

```
SELECT G.StyleID, 
G.Size, Count(*) As 'Count', 
G.PropertyID FROM TBL_Garment G 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_EmployeeJob ON TBL_EmployeeJob.ID = G.EmployeeJobID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_DepartmentJob ON TBL_DepartmentJob.ID = TBL_EmployeeJob.DepartmentJobID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Department ON TBL_Department.ID = TBL_DepartmentJob.DepartmentID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Division ON TBL_Division.ID = TBL_Department.DivisionID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_Job ON TBL_Job.ID = TBL_DepartmentJob.JobID 
WHERE G.EmployeejobiD IS NOT NULL  
AND TBL_Division.ID = N'1'  
AND TBL_Department.ID = N'1'  
AND TBL_Job.ID = N'1'  
AND G.PropertyID = 1 
GROUP BY G.StyleID, G.Size, G.PropertyID 
ORDER BY G.StyleID
```

and here are the results returned by this query:

[image]

Now I need 2 extra columns in this table:

One is the sum of the count by StyleID (As Total), and the other is Count/Total.

I am sure I can get the count/Total on my own, but do not know how to get the Total column, or even if it is possible.

Below is a version of how I would like the table to be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function:

```
sum([Count]) over (partition by [StyleID])
```

Make sure it's good enough for you performance-wise, though.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to include that, I am getting 'Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.'

Comment: @Alex Are you seriously trying to tell me that your `Count` column is a `varchar`? :D

Comment: @Liaan, I cant see how it could be, as it is only delcared in the query ?

Comment: @Alex Well, I can see that you're comparing the IDs to nvarchars, so it wouldn't be that much of a surprise, but... I didn't notice you're actually wanting a sum of counts - I assumed you already had a count as a field. Hm. You might have to wrap this query in another query, and apply the `sum([Count]) over (...)` there instead.